# Loading a view within a fragment on click?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-view

I have a RelativeLayout with an Imageview inside of it. When I click the ImageView, I need to call an Async task to get some data and display it at the bottom of my screen in a RecyclerView. Like this:

**Before** clicking anything:

[image]

**Click on ImageView -->** (Calls Async task and displays progress bar):

[image]

**Result**:

[image]

I have the initial layout working (the first image) but I'm not sure how to reorganize my layout to make this whole thing happen on click. I would also need to be able to have the RecyclerView grow as I will be allowing the user to load more "comments" in that bottom section.

The simplified layout I have right now is basically this:

```
<!--Does all of this belong in a ScrollView to allow for the comments section at the bottom? -->
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Lots of TextViews and buttons-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_picture_with_unknown_size"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content/>
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_comments"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                           
            android:background="@drawable/ic_comments" />

    <!-- Do I need to put the comments section here in a FrameLayout?-->
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have a click listener on the imageview that I want to use as the trigger for the comments section. How do I expand/load the view on click?

Comment: you can refer this to help you [Create a list with RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java) and on the click of button call a method which will initiate the recycler view

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

1. Add a recycler view to your layout and hide it by `android:visibility="gone"`.
2. Implement a RecyclerView Adapter and set it to your RecyclerView
3. When user clicks on the image, start your AsyncTask. After task finishes, get your list and give it to your adapter. Notify the adapter to refresh itself with new data by simply calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` from your activity. Now you have a full recycler view. You can set `recyclerView.setVisibility(true);`

To implement infinite scroll, you can do something like this:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    if (layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == adapter.getItemCount() - 1) {
                          // LOAD MORE COMMENTS AND ADD GIVE THEM TO YOUR ADAPTER 
                    }
                }
            });
```

Hope it makes sense.